# Range based for loop never exits Visual Studio 2013 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have the following method:

```
void printDetections( vector<Detection> detections )
{
    auto i = 0;
    for ( auto& detection : detections )
    {
        cout << "Index: " << i++ << " Size: " << detections.size() << endl;
    }
}
```

and the output I see is currently:
[image: output]

Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: Do you know what the actual size of vector<Detections> is? Can you post the declaration of this container? What is Detection?

Comment: Show your real code. I've just tried this based on the code you supplied here (with my own definition of `Dectection` and it works just fine.

Comment: Any decent compiler can't have a bug on a so simple example. Bugs usually can survive in dark corners of coding, not in full light....

Comment: Compiler bugs do happen, or bugs in libraries, but something this obvious should have been discovered early.  Ensure that you have applied all available patches to your VS installation.  Otherwise, as others have pointed out:  how are you calling this function; what are you passing it?  Usually problems this strange have very trivial causes, like memory corruption elsewhere.

Comment: Think I got it. Seems to be a mismatch between Header and DLL. A double was added to the Detection struct that was compiled in DLL but not visible in the header file. As this is an optional parameter for the constructor neither compiler nor linker complained.